# Query slow for certain criteria on clustered index

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table called readings that has > 76 million rows in it that I'm running this query on:

```
declare @tunnel_id int = 13
SELECT TOP 1 local_time, recorded_time
FROM readings
WHERE tunnel_id = @tunnel_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The id column is a bigint, set as the primary key, and has a clustered index, and there is also an index on the tunnel_id field.

The works great and returns in less than a second for about 16 out of the 20 different tunnel_id's I'm trying.  However, on the last 4 or so the query takes 40 seconds and uses hundreds of thousands of reads.

I tried modifying the query into this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) local_time, recorded_time
FROM readings
where id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 id
    FROM readings
    WHERE tunnel_id = 13
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
```

Which once again is only slow for a few tunnel_id's.  What perplexes me more is that the inner select runs quickly for the slow id's and if I hardcode the maximum id instead of the subquery it also runs quickly.

What am I missing here that's making this query perform poorly?

Edit for comments:

Tunnel_id is not unique, each tunnel has multiple millions of rows.  This is running on Sql Server 2012.

I included the actual execution plans from both the fast and slow runs and they are identical.

Fast:
[image: sql fast execution plan]

Slow:

[image: sql fast execution plan]

But as you can see, the first executes in less than a second while the second takes 51 seconds.

Comment: I'm guessing a big part of it is your `ORDER BY id DESC` - by default your probably have the clustered index on `id ASC`, so there's likely a sort happening in the background.

Comment: Why do you have a subquery in the first place?

Comment: Suggest trying your query wrapped in a stored procedure with a parameter for tunel_id. Something strange may be going on with the otimizer and how the execution plan is cached. Broadly speaking, according to Micrsoft Press' Book 70-461, Query Microsoft SQL Server, the query plans are cached more efficiently for stored procedures when compared with ad hoc queries. Just a thought.

Comment: Is the index at tunnel_id unique? What version of SQL Server are you using? Could you post also the execution plans for the "slow" and "fast" case?

Comment: I've included answers to your questions @Alejandro.  As for the optimizer Karl, I've tried using option(recompile) in the query to no effect which has fixed other similar issues for me in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that you can hint to use the tunnel_id index:

```
declare @tunnel_id int = 13
SELECT TOP 1 local_time, recorded_time
FROM readings
WITH (INDEX(idx_tunnel_id))
WHERE tunnel_id = @tunnel_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

which works as expected and returns in less than 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

The plan basically scans the entire clustered index from start to end and looks for the first row with tunnel_id = @tunnel_id.

My educated guess is that the 'slow' tunnels don't have any rows in the beginning of the clustered index and so it has to scan more of it.

This non-clustered index should speed things up:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FOO] ON [readings]
(
    tunnel_id, 
    ID 
)
INCLUDE 
(
    local_time, 
    recorded_time
)
```

This could replace the existing index on tunnel_id.

Comment: Almost same answer at almost same time :P
Interesting in adding the id at the key, but would it be better if it where desc, as in the query?

Comment: @Alejandro -- ha! :) yes putting ID in the index instead of in the include will allow a direct seek to the single row. Good point about DESC. I believe it will be able to use it anyway (just do a backward scan) but this should be tested of course.

Comment: I agree. Likely the values matching `tunnel_id=13` are all at the end of the index. SQL Server will assume they are equally distributed. [Using trace flag 9130](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/12/06/my-new-favourite-traceflag.aspx) will show how many rows were actually scanned before the `TOP 1` was found. BTW if `ID` is the clustered index key then it will already be automatically included as a key column in non unique non clustered indexes.

Comment: I used the trace flag 9103 and actual number of rows scanned is ~53 million.  I do think this index would help this particular query but I'm hesitant to do it since the table is already 3.5gb and the index is already 5.8gb.  There are many other queries that I think would be adversely affected by changing the index.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part here is that SQL isn't using the index in tunnel_id at all and is just scanning the table in whole, which is slow if it's big like 76 millions rows.
I think the real cause it isn't using it is because the ordering by id, as it must perform a lookup and then an additional sorting. I doubt at first that parameter sniffing is the main problem here.

I would try to change the index instead, and make it covering. If possible include in the index the local time, recorded time and the id (not 100% sure if it's needed as it's the cluster key anyway).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tunnel_id ON dbo.readings (tunnel_id) INCLUDE (id, local_time, recorded_time)
```

Note that, while this can improve this particular query, it will make inserts and updates a little slower, and require additional storage space.